# Advanced Search using childNode in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm using the swift function `childNode(withName: String, recursively: Bool)` to search a child node in a parent node in my 3D map.

So, my map is loading correctly and I'm trying to use this function.

I've tried on a single node `EntranceGround` and it worked, yeah!

But when I tried to use an Advanced Search to collect the child `primitive_0` in parent node `Scene`, it didn't work at all and I don't know why.

Documentation to advanced search : [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/searching_the_node_tree)

Here is the exemple for a simple search :

```swift
if let screenbox = map.childNode(withName: "EntranceGround", recursively: true) 
 {
   /// Function called to create a object Zone
   _ = self.createZone(name: "Hall", in: screenbox)
 } else {
   /// I use NSLogger to have a better console log, its the equivalent of print()
   Logger.shared.log(.app, .error, "Didn't find the Hall node")
 }
```

and here's the response on the console, it worked well, my object was created

```sh
Zone of Hall : Size --> <SCNBox: 0x28326c380 | width=21.345 height=1.194 length=28.079 chamferRadius=0.000> || Center --> SCNVector3(x: 0.0037841797, y: -0.5817822, z: 10.556584)
```

Now i use, a complexe search to look primitive_0 in Scene :

```swift
if let screenbox = map.childNode(withName: "//Scene/primitive_0", recursively: true) {
  _ = self.createZone(name: "Hall", in: screenbox)
} else {
  Logger.shared.log(.app, .error, "Didn't find the primitive_0 node")
}
```

and here the response, the system didn't find my object: `Didn't find the primitive_0 node`

If someone can help me to find what I am doing wrong :)

Comment: I would assume that there is no child called "//Scane/primitive_0".

You could try recursively map through all the children, printing the names of nodes in it. Is it possible that it's just called "primitive_0"?